# Data modeling BigQuery - Consolidate data from multiple streams into a single table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-modeling

What is better or what do you recommend?
I have multiple data streams from different tax applications that I want to consolidate into one.
But there are data flows that may have different fields than others.
Is it preferable to change the table structure as I add new streams (jobs that do inserts) or to do it in separate tables?
Always thinking about scalability and performance.
This final table will be used for learning models

I currently create a denormalized (flatten) table where as I incorporate flows I make changes to the table structure, obviously these fields will be null for flows that do not use them.
I also thought about json fields, would it be a good option? Would it be a correct use for this situation? Is the structure used so far correct?